# Java - ExceptionType to catch any exception

Tags: java, exception

What `ExceptionType` should be used in Java to catch any exception that occurs in `try` block.
I just want to know that there is error in `try` block so that i can `exit` the program

```
try {

} catch (ExceptionType name) {

}
```

Comment: Please go through the basic

Comment: can you elaborate what you actually asking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)

Comment: Use the exception type that's being thrown from the method call. for e.g. when doing IO operation, most of JDK api throws IOException so catch that exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `java.lang.Exception` to catch *most* exceptions. Whether you *should* or not is debatable: perhaps a function higher up the call stack can deal with the exception more appropriately.

The true catch-all is `java.lang.Thowable`. But take care when intercepting that as doing so can interfere with the workings of the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch java.lang.Exception or java.lang.Throwable.
Be aware, that it is anti-pattern to catch all Exceptions.